# Should I lubricate rear derailleur wheels

Tags: derailleur-rear, lubricant

Replacing the chain I found  that the plastic wheels of the rear derailleur are rotating with high resistance.

So I disassembled the wheel, cleaned it from dirt and sprayed with WD-40. Here is how it looks now:

[image]

I have Motul Tech grease 300, that I used to lubricate the ball bearings in the hub. So, should I put the grease between the steel cylinder (how is it called?) and the inner round hole of the wheel?

Or it will just attract dirt and make things worse?

Comment: If you lube your chain regularly the jockey wheels end up getting lubed as well.

Comment: @DanielRHicks It was filled with old lube mixed with sand and dirt, that created sort of a dirty paste.

Comment: Yep, you do need to clean the jockey wheels occasionally.  How, and how often depends on a number of factors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually if they're turning as you describe with high resistance, they're either gunked up and need cleaning or they're put together wrong. They should spin very freely without any added lubrication. Grease would probably tend to do as you say and attract dirt, but a thin coating on the outside of the bushing isn't going to ruin anything if you want to try it. I do a drop of light lube at the gap of each one to keep them running quietly, but it's usually a negligible difference either way.

Comment: "bushing" is the name of the steel cylinder? A little bit of light oil on it's outer surface? And a little on the screw?

Comment: They were gunked up, they are rotating freely after I cleaned them.

Comment: Yep, the steel cylinder is a bushing. I just lube around the metal shield parts on the assembled derailer. It will get worked around as needed. Note we're talking about a few drops of light oil only.

Comment: @NathanKnutson comments should be used to refine the answer instead of becoming a conversation.  I'd suggest editing the stuff about bush into the answer.